# How can I open multiple popups in succession?

Tags: python, kivy, pyserial

I'm currently working on an application written in Kivy in python.
I have 2 multiprocessing.Processes running:

- One is a process for the RFID-reader, I open a popup that lets me choose a screen to go to.
- The second process is for Serial communication.

I use queues to communicate with my main thread, and that works great. The problem I'm facing at the moment is I need to introduce a learning process to my Kivy program.
I have 4 screens which I call

- mainscreen
- adminscreen
- managementscreen
- initialscreen <- This screen runs only once, once it's set, the screen won't be accessable anymore.

This is the function that gets called when I push the button inside the initialscreen:

```
def startLearningProcess(self, lockeramount):
        self.lockeramount = int(lockeramount)
        with Database(self.databasepath) as db:
            db.truncate_table('LOCKERS')
            # resetting primary key sequence to make the ids start from 1
            db.reset_primary_key_sequence('LOCKERS')
        for locker in range(int(lockeramount)):
            # use a with statement to automatically close the db after the operations
            with Database(self.databasepath) as db:
                # inserting the given amount lockers to the database as rows. 
                db.insertLockerRow(locker+1,'Pieter')
```

if I add the following to the function, 5 popups get opened all at once:

```
while self.lockeramount != 0:
    popup = Popup(title='Test popup', auto_dismiss=True, content=Label(text='Hello world'), size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    popup.open()
    self.lockeramount -= 1
```

When I input the number 5 into my interface, I want to have 5 popups to open up for me one by one. How can I make it so when I push a button I open up 1 popup, instead of all 5 at once? I apologize for my grammar, english is not my first language.

EDIT:
while John's answer worked perfectly, I was looking for another solution that did not use threading. I solved it by doing the following:

In my `class InitialScreen(Screen):` I added 2 variables, a bool that starts out with False (`booleanUp`) and a int variable that starts at 0 (`lockeramount`).
When I enter my `def startLearningProcess` I set the `lockeramount` variable to the number I input into my screen. I added an interval to the startLearningProcess function: `Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.schedule_popups(), 1)`. I then added the following functions:

```
def close_popup(self, instance):
    self.booleanUp = False

def schedule_popups(self):
    if self.lockeramount > 0 and not self.booleanUp:
        print(f'opening up popup {self.lockeramount}')
        popup = Popup(title='MyPopup', content=Label(text='Abba ' + str(self.lockeramount)), size_hint=(0.5, 0.5))
        popup.bind(on_dismiss=self.close_popup)
        self.lockeramount -= 1
        self.booleanUp = True
        popup.open()
    else:
        print('not opening another popup')
```

When I open a new popup, I set the boolean to true, so that with the next interval it won't open another interval. I made an on_dismiss event that resets the variable back to False and bound it to my popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Queue` to make the `Popups` wait. Define a custom `Popup` that accepts a `Queue` in its `__init__()` method, and sends something (could even be `None`) to the `Queue` when it is dismissed. And your loop can use the `Queue` to wait for the `Popups` to be dismissed.

Here is a custom `Popup` that uses a `Queue`:

```
class MyPopup(Popup):
    queue = ObjectProperty(None)

    def dismiss(self, *_args, **kwargs):
        super(MyPopup, self).dismiss(*_args, **kwargs)
        if self.queue:
            self.queue.put(None)
```

For this to work, you must run it in another thread. Otherwise, waiting for the `Queue` on the main thread will never end, because holding the main thread will prevent the `Popup` from dismissing. Here is some code that shows 5 `Popups` in succession, one at a time:

```
def doit(self):
    threading.Thread(target=self.popup_thread).start()

def popup_thread(self):
    self.queue = Queue()
    for i in range(5):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.show_popup)
        self.queue.get()

def show_popup(self, dt):
    popup = MyPopup(title='MyPopup', content=Label(text='Abba ' + str(dt)), size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), queue=self.queue)
    popup.open()
```

To start the `Popups`, just call the `doit()` method, probably as an action associated with a `Button`.

Comment: Awesome solution! hadn't thought of using queues for the popups yet. +1